# How to change the EditText background Tint color in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, background-color, material-design

I am developing an app using `Material` theme. In my app, I'm having multiple edit texts to get the input from user.

I've divided the screen into two portions:

- top portion background color is white background so it showing the default material theme style but
- bottom portion I'm using the blue color,

If I'm using the same style in the bottom portion, `EditText` background tint not visible clearly. So I'm planning to change the background tint color.It supports the `lollipop` version. I want to show style for below versions also.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this. `android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat#setTint`

With this you can set the tint to your EditText.

[DrawableCompat](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response.How can i set the drawable for edittext?